# Copying/Moving App Code to New Project

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-config, assemblies, app-code

Ok, I am in the process of breaking apart of intranet application (VS 2010 Web Site, ASP.NET Web Forms with VB code behind). During this process i'm trying to convert some of our our app_code files in to WCF rest service in a new project. However, when I copy or "add existing" vb files into the new "services" project. I get tons of errors including...

1. error BC30002: Type 'XXX' is not defined
2. warning BC40056: Namespace
   or type specified in the Imports 'System.ServiceModel' doesn't
   contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the
   namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public
   member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases.

From what i've read it may (or may not) have something to do with Assemblies and references that I just have very little knowledge on. I have added the namespaces from the current web.config to new project's web.config, and the files are identical. So there is something in the background that needs to be added to the new project I just don't know what its.

PLEASE HELP!!

THANKS
JOSH

**UPDATE 1**

So one of the errors i'm getting = "error BC30002: Type 'MailMessage' is not defined." Which is a namespace that is added to the web.config, which apparently isn't being picked up??? IDEAS?

Comment: <add namespace="System.Net.Mail"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue seems to be tied to the the differences between Web Application Projects versus Web Site Projects. Eventually I had to add different namespaces on the new project level.

Here is more info about WAP vs WSP.... 
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I've come across a similar issue - not sure what the reasoning behind it is, but I got around it by creating a new .vb class with the same name as the one you want to copy, then copy and paste all the text from the old one to the new one. Save it, then it seems to like it - it didn't like me copying and pasting the actual file, nor did it like me adding existing files.

Hope this helps :/

Comment: this didn't work :\ still get all kinds of errors that I shouldn't. Example "error BC30002: Type 'MailMessage' is not defined." which when you Google it says to bring in the namespace which it has. :-\